# Laravel migrating file cache to redis

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, migration

I have an existing application with a ton of cache files written using the Laravel file driver. These follow a specific directory and naming structure (e.g):

```
cache/data/
    2d/
        6e/
            2d6eece558d9143286c4a08bb5757bb2cb6e9h9kf
```

And if it has an expiry, the first 10 chars of the file is the expiry timestamp in unix time.

`1605235030a:3:{s:3:"price";s:6:"342.99"......`

I want to migrate my entire cache directory to redis. If it can't be done, I can handle losing the expiring ones, but I have a bunch that are `Cache::forever` that ideally we should keep (to avoid a couple of nagging legacy issues). Redis stores keys as plain-text, not as a hash. How does one migrate these across? Bonus points if you can do it for expiring cache files too.

Obviously it's clear if we rely on cache items in `Cache::forever` then we need to change the way that works (likely store that info in DB instead of cache if it's functional data), but for the sake of not losing a bunch of data, is this possible?

Sessions are fine, they are hashed the same both in redis and as file cache.

Comment: You should not worried about losing cache.

Comment: @tirtakeniten thank you for your insight, however you cannot make a call about that for me. As I said in the post I am not overly worried, but `Cache::forever` items are important and due to legacy reasons would like to migrate them. Additionally the app supports a few hundred thousand users and clearing the cache will affect a large portion of them and their user experience, albeit only briefly. It's enough that a smooth transition of the cache would be better than deleting everything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved it now?

I am looking at the same challenge and as I did not yet find a solution will build something shortly.
Solution direction for me is to hold the 2 caches in parallel for a little while. I.e.:

```
$value = Cache::store('redis')->remember('users', $seconds, function () {
    return Cache::store('file')->pull('users', function () {
        return DB::table('users')->get();
    });
});
```

by using 'pull' on the filecache you may be able to see its size come down as your users help populate redis....

(ps - Tirta; sure caches should be fully disposable, but that does not mean they come without a cost. A migration may be a lower cost than a replace)

Comment: I migrated a few items in this way, with so many cache files it's not feasible to work out what is in each one, and so you'd need to know the keys for every file. For the most part I could rebuild them as most were specific to users, but sessions/temp data I had to lose.